# How to read from file in temp?

Tags: java, file

i have problem, how to read file in temp and get filename ?

```
  tempFile = File.createTempFile("MyFile.txt", ".tmp" );
  System.out.print("Created temporary file with name ");
  System.out.println(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to read a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

1. Reading a file in a temporary directory is done in exactly the same way as non-temporary files are read.
2. `getAbsolutePath()` returns the absolute path name of the file. If by "file name" you refer to just the "file" portion of the path name, use the `getName()` method.